# How to solve NoClassDefFoundError when using jackson in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

When I using jackson in spring boot, I've got an `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:756)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:666)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:353)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:300)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1082)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1071)
    at com.xxxx.Application.main(Application.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    ......
    ......
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:597)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.jacksonObjectMapper(JacksonAutoConfiguration.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$11271f08.CGLIB$jacksonObjectMapper$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$11271f08$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ce52140f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$11271f08.jacksonObjectMapper(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

And I run the `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=com.fasterxml.jackson.core` command then got:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ xxxx-common ---
[INFO] com.xxxx.rc:xxxx-common:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.11:compile
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xxxx-dao 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ xxxx-dao ---
[INFO] com.xxxx.rc:xxxx-dao:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.xxxx.rc:xxxx-common:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO]       +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO]       \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.11:compile
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xxxx-service 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ xxxx-service ---
[INFO] com.xxxx.rc:xxxx-service:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.xxxx.rc:xxxx-dao:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    \- com.xxxx.rc:xxxx-common:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]       \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO]          +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO]          \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.11:compile
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xxxx-rpc 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ xxxx-rpc ---
[INFO] com.xxxx.rc:xxxx-rpc:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.xxxx.rc:xxxx-service:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    \- com.xxxx.rc:xxxx-dao:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]       \- com.xxxx.rc:xxxx-common:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]          \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO]             +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO]             \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.11:compile
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xxxx-controller 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ xxxx-controller ---
[INFO] com.xxxx.rc:xxxx-controller:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.xxxx.rc:xxxx-rpc:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    \- com.xxxx.rc:xxxx-service:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]       \- com.xxxx.rc:xxxx-dao:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]          \- com.xxxx.rc:xxxx-common:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]             \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO]                +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO]                \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.11:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] xxxx ................................. SUCCESS [  0.736 s]
[INFO] xxxx-common .......................... SUCCESS [  0.340 s]
[INFO] xxxx-dao ............................. SUCCESS [  0.070 s]
[INFO] xxxx-service ......................... SUCCESS [  0.284 s]
[INFO] xxxx-rpc ............................. SUCCESS [  0.104 s]
[INFO] xxxx-controller ........................... SUCCESS [  0.185 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

And here is my usage of json.

```
public class JsonUtils {

    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    static {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES, true);

    }

    public static String toString(Object object) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("parse object to json string error", e);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my maven config.

```
<dependencyManagement>
  ...
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.2</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencyManagement>
```

The spring boot version is `1.5.22.RELEASE`. I don't know what cause the problem, Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Check the complete dependency tree without `-Dincludes=com.fasterxml.jackson.core` and check if multiple versions of jackson are present

Comment: @Smile I checked and  there is no multiple versions of jackson.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue and it got resolved after adding below dependency.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```